# How do I enter information into an Access Database through C#?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, oledb

I'm developing the username/password creation system for my program. It's just going to be used in a computing lab, and I'm just going to have a central Access database that distributes through scripts on the lab machines. Or that's the plan right now. I can't remember the proper code to insert the info into the database to save my life though. This is what I've got so far. The hashing and salting seem to be going fine, I just can't shove it into the database. The name of the table is regulate.

I'm getting "number of query fields and destination fields are not the same".

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=access.mdb";
        conn.Open();
        string Name = txtName.Text;
        string PW = txtHash.Text;
        string Salt = txtSalt.Text;
        OleDbCommand cmmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO regulate(regulate) Values(@NAME, @PASSWORD, @SALT)", conn);
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cmmd.Parameters.Add("@NAME", OleDbType.VarWChar, 100).Value = Name;
            cmmd.Parameters.Add("@PASSWORD", OleDbType.VarWChar, 500).Value = PW;
            cmmd.Parameters.Add("@SALT", OleDbType.VarWChar, 10).Value = Salt;
            try
            {
                cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("DATA ADDED");
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (OleDbException expe)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(expe.Message);
                conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`OleDbCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) uses a different format for parameters than `SqlCommand`, as you see in the documentation:

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an `OleDbCommand` when `CommandType` is set to `Text`. In this case, the question mark (`?`) placeholder must be used.

And as [@codenheim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26569289/1715579) suggests, check the syntax of your `INSERT` command.

Also, `PASSWORD` is a [reserved word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/sql-reserved-words-HP001032249.aspx) in Jet SQL, so you probably need to quote that column name. I believe either these quote styles would work:

```
INSERT INTO regulate(name, `password`, salt) Values(?, ?, ?)
```

```
INSERT INTO regulate(name, [password], salt) Values(?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: +1 for position parameter suggestion. I usually use the db specific ADO providers or Devart dotConnect so I wasn't aware of this limitation.

Comment: @codenheim +1 good catch on the syntax error, too. I think once OP fixed the parameters that would have been the next thing he would have to deal with.

Comment: I'm at `OleDbCommand cmmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO regulate (NAME, PASSWORD, SALT) " + "VALUES (?, ?, ?)", conn);` and getting "Syntax error in INSERT INTO command" at this point. I started with the values within the same quotes as you said, got the same error, just trying a different syntax in a failed effort to get past the error.

Comment: @AarronDixon `PASSWORD` is a reserved word in Access. See my updated answer.

Comment: NAME too, I'm pretty sure. It's weird how after you figure something out, it seems so obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The number of fields and types in this:

```
INSERT INTO regulate(regulate)
```

must match this:

```
Values(var1, var2, var3)
```

Should be something like:

```
INSERT INTO regulate(name, password, salt) Values(?, ?, ?)
```

assuming these are the column names.

PS: I don't use OleDb very often, but I believe you need `?` instead of named `@arg` per @p.s.w.g's answer. (Upvote his/her answer if this helps). I can confirm all of my OleDb code does indeed use positional arguments only.

Comment: 'OleDbCommand cmmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO regulate(NAME,PASSWORD,SALT) Values(?, ?, ?)", conn);' but now it gives me syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Comment: No. It all goes into one record, so 1 insert per record is customary.

Answer (score 1):

First important thing is to make sure that your path to your `access.mdb` is correct.
Then also make sure that if your supplying 3 parameters to your insert statement (in your case, the `@NAME`, `@PASSWORD`, `@SALT`), you must also have a matching column each for those 3 parameters to assign to.

```
string cs = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=access.mdb";
OleDbConnection c = new OleDbConnection(cs);

string Name = txtName.Text;
string PW = txtHash.Text;
string Salt = txtSalt.Text;

try
{
    c.Open();

    string s = "INSERT INTO regulate(NAME, PASSWORD, SALT) Values (@NAME, @PASSWORD, @SALT)";
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(s, c))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASSWORD", PW);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SALT", Salt);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("DATA ADDED");
    }
}
catch (OleDbException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    c.Close();
}
```

Comment: Getting the exact same "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement" as the other attempts. I manage to create my first hashing and salting password system no problem, then run into a giant roadblock on inserting the data into a database. Always the simple things, lol.